# Pass 2 dimensional array double[][] to a c# windows application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, double

I am trying to use a dll in a c# windows application. this dll is expecting one double[][] parameter( more than 10000 values)  and another double[] parameter.

```
public static double[] CalcResults(double[][] Positions, double[] Values)
```

I am not quite sure how to declare this variable in the c# class. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this DLL a native DLL, or a .NET class library? What have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: I don't understand. double[][] is valid in C#.

Comment: I was handed this dll without much documentation. I opened the dll in ILDisassembler and found a header info that said : Metadata version: v2.0.50727 

I am getting the following error message when I assign values to the variable declared as double[,]. 

The best overloaded method match for  has some invalid arguments
Argument '1': cannot convert from 'double[*,*]' to 'double[][]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double[][] positions = new double[size1][];
```

**Edit**:  Better yet, try this:

```
double[,] positions = new double[size1, size2];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(v=vs.100).aspx

**Edit2**:  [Doing Arrays - C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161465/Doing-Arrays-C) shows the difference between jagged arrays ([][]) and regular two-dimensional arrays ([,]).

Comment: Thanks @zimdanen. Your answer provided me with the essential starting point.
I initialized the variable as
double[][] positions = new double[3][];
            positions[0]=new double [5];
            positions[1] = new double[10];
and it does not throw any more errors.